# I found this code for conditional buttons but I don't understand the on_number(self, obj, value) code

Tags: button, conditional-statements, kivy, kivy-language

I'm very new to kivy. So I found this code online, and I don't understand the section for on_number. I know that if I remove it, the number would be updated but it won't repeat the process for creating a widget. Could someone please explain how the function for on_number works and what the three variables refer to?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<SubWidget1>:
    Label:
        text: 'number is bigger than 3'
    Button:
        text: 'click here to decrease'
        on_press: root.parent.number -= 1

<SubWidget2>:
    Label:
        text: 'number is smaller than 3'
    Button:
        text: 'click here to increase'
        on_press: root.parent.number += 1

<MyWidget>
    number: 0
''')

class SubWidget1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SubWidget2(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    number = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args)
        self.widget = None
        self._create_widget()

    def _create_widget(self):
        print(self.number)
        if self.widget is not None:
            self.remove_widget(self.widget)
        if self.number > 3:
            self.widget = SubWidget1()
        else:
            self.widget = SubWidget2()
        self.add_widget(self.widget)

    def on_number(self, obj, value):
        self._create_widget()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Kivy properties will automatically call a method of their class based on the property name when they change. This method is `on_propertyname`, and is passed two arguments: the object whose property just changed, and the new value of the property.